# Adding a pre integrated cloud application on G Suite

Tags: single-sign-on, google-workspace, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I have a SAML-enabled web app, and many of our customers use G Suite as an identity provider. We have been working with each of them to set up a custom SAML app so they can use G Suite to SSO onto our app, but we would really like to be listed as a pre-integrated app, as described [in the blog](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/09/new-applications-added-g-suite-sso.html) and [the support docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519).

After hours of independent searching and chatting with G Suite support, I've been unable to find any sort of application form to get my app listed. This process was really straightforward with IdPs like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/integrate/documentation/single-sign-on/), [Azure ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-app-gallery-listing), etc... and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it for G Suite. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cycling through 3 different G Suite support reps, eventually one connected me to a different G Suite support rep who emailed me a link to a Google form where I submitted the details of my request. Evidently I'll hear back sometime in the next month. I would link the form here but I don't want to run afoul of the powers that be while my submission is still under review ;)

Comment: Reviving an old thread because it's literally the only topic I've found with the same question I have. Replying in the hope that you had some success and can elaborate on it now?